# SVN Ant echo the error from the logfile

Tags: java, svn, ant

How to echo the error in the log-file ?

```
<svn refid="svn.settings" logFile="C:/Logfile.log">
                <export destpath="LOCAL Location" 
                    srcUrl="Source Url" />
                </svn>
```

When I run the above `export` I dont get error in the build, the error is displayed in the log file ,URL doesn't exists.

I want to catch the error in the logfile and echo it , how to do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't need the logfile, you can omit the logfile parameter and it will be printed to the console.
Also see [here](http://subclipse.tigris.org/svnant/svntask.html)

Otherwise you can just load the file and print to console with a seperate ant task:

```
<loadfile property="svnLog" srcFile="C:/Logfile.log"/> 
<echo>${svnLog}</echo>
```

Comment: thank you. you were helpful. ill post another question relate to this can you check it please ? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42746637/svn-ant-loadfile-show-only-error