# Echo a single line of an SvnAnt error message using Ant

Tags: java, svn, ant, svnant

If the SvnAnt `<export>` has an error, the Ant `<loadfile>` task will show all of it on the console.

```
<svn refid="svn.settings" logFile="C:/Logfile.log">
    <export destpath="LOCAL Location" srcUrl="Source Url" />
</svn>
<loadfile property="svnLog" srcFile="C:/Logfile.log"/>
<echo>${svnLog}</echo>
```

```
[echo] <Export> started ...
[echo] export --no-auth-cache -r HEAD https://lbsm8-svn.path.local/svn/DB_Scripts/SCRIPTS/Reporting/FTR/ORAX/ftr1241000000430105_orax.pbd D:\Copyof\anttt\RET\ORA
[echo] svn: E170000: URL'https://svn.apache.org/repos/infra/websites/production/commons/content/proper/commons-rng'
[echo] <Export> failed.
[echo] the execution failed for some reason. cause: Can't export
[echo]  at org.tigris.subversion.svnant.commands.SvnCommand.ex(Unknown Source)
[echo]  at org.tigris.subversion.svnant.commands.Export.execute(Unknown Source)
[echo]  at org.tigris.subversion.svnant.commands.SvnCommand.executeCommand(Unknown Source)
[echo]  at org.tigris.subversion.svnant.SvnTask.executeImpl(Unknown Source)
[echo]  at org.tigris.subversion.svnant.SvnTask.execute(Unknown Source)
[echo]  at org.apache.tools.ant.UnknownElement.execute(UnknownElement.java:288)
```

Can I only show this from the logfile and disregard the rest?

```
[echo] svn: E170000: URL'https://svn.apache.org/repos/infra/websites/production/commons/content/proper/commons-rng'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`<linecontains>` FilterChain](https://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/filterchain.html#linecontains) can be given to `<loadfile>` to extract just the line you want from the file:

```
<loadfile property="svnLog" srcFile="C:/Logfile.log">
    <filterchain>
        <linecontains>
            <contains value="svn: E170000:"/>
        </linecontains>
    </filterchain>
</loadfile>
<echo>${svnLog}</echo>
```

### Output

```
[echo] svn: E170000: URL'https://svn.apache.org/repos/infra/websites/production/commons/content/proper/commons-rng'
```